# which stream type handles keyboard

Tags: c#, stream

C# has several stream types - FileStream, NetworkStream etc.

1. If I want to pick one type to associate with keyboard entry, which stream that that would be?
2. When eventually stream means bytes only whether its on network, file etc. WHy we need different stream types?

Answer (score 2):

1) You don't have to pick a Stream for the Keyboard. The Console class exposes it as a `TextReader`.
`TextReader` is not a Stream but a Stream decorator.

2) We have different streams for different media. And they are only about bytes (not 'eventually').
And we use TextReader, BinaryReader and Serialization classes to deal with non-byte data in a consistent way, regardless of the medium.

Comment: You're too fast for me. I was at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.in.aspx for a moment.

Comment: still.... conceptually if I tell someone that there are 5-6 types of stream and these streams are specialized for different scenarios. And I am queried, what about byte that passes from keyboard to machine... logically which stream type can it be linked to (for analogy purpose). THen? I think it is conceptually network stream as actually some one must be listening to keyboard port. Howzz that :D ?

Comment: Conceptually, they are all `abstract class Stream`. Except the keybd, it is implemented as a Stream-decorator without an actual stream.